# Compiling C programs with static files

Tags: c, g++

I am trying to compile a c program with a static library and its not working .

This is the error :

> undefined reference to `calculatearea'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status .

The static files were made with the gcc / g++ compilers .

This is the main code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int calculatearea(int a , int b);
int main()
{


int c = calculatearea(2,4);

printf("%d",c);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

edit : 
: [screenshot of compiler error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xPTvcW7BoDl9tkLcAbGxzaGNYRvby6TW/view)

Comment: Or a very clear explanation on how to compile static library will be appreciated

Comment: Let us find more information. Try `objdump -t mylibrary.a`. Examine the output. Does `calculatearea` appear?

Comment: This is the link to a screen shot of the compiler after running that command :            https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xPTvcW7BoDl9tkLcAbGxzaGNYRvby6TW

Comment: In short form yes it appears

Comment: Then I know no easy solution. I run Debian GNU/Linux rather than Windows, so I do not believe that I could accurately walk you through your build. Building libraries is tricky. It is temperamental. Bugs during linking are hard to diagnose. Someone else might know an easier solution, but I fear that all I can to is to refer you to [the manual of GNU's libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/). That is not easy or short to read, but reading it is how I learned to build libraries.

Comment: But you did not define the function `calculatearea` at all!

Comment: @L.F. did you see my screenshot ? and its meant to be defined in the library

Comment: I don’t see your screenshot in your question. Please include it in the question if you want others to see it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional details, instead of burying them in comments. One of the most important things you could add is the exact compiler command line you're using, and the information that `calculatearea` is in `area.o`.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code we can see that you have declared the function `int calculatearea(int a , int b);` but have not written any definition for the same. and you are calling this function in the main. compiler is not finding the definition for the function `calculatearea` and giving error.

To solve this:

1) Write the definition for function `calculatearea` in the same file.

2) Make use of `extern` specifier with this function declaration and make sure that definition is present with the link library at the time of compilation.

3) As mentioned in the picture if the area.o have the definition of function `calculatearea`, then compile as below, this will generate a.out in linux:

```
gcc filename.c area.o
```

Comment: Thank you it worked , the only complication to this is when i use multiple externs to link different .o files . Its only the area that gets noticed the other give an error undefined refference